# How to force browsers not to cache destination of redirects

Tags: php, redirect, caching, browser

I am working on a PHP script that redirects to a random URL on my blog by adding a query like "?random" to the URL. The problem is that some browsers seem to cache the destination and so the "?random" parameter always redirects to the same page. For some browsers I managed to prevent the caching by redirecting with the code "307", but now I discovered that Firefox 57 still caches that link.

Is there any recommended redirection code for that purpose, or any other workaround? I am aware that I could just add a dummy parameter with a random token like "?random&token=..." but I want that visitors can use that link from their own websites where I obviously cannot add a random token.

Comment: Where's your code?

Comment: Use `Cache-Control` HTTP header.

Comment: @charlotte-dunois `Cache-Control` is a great idea, thanks!

Comment: Tested it, works! 
`header( 'Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate' );
header( 'Location: ' . $permalink, true, 307 );
exit;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on @charlotte-dunois comment, now as complete answer to the question:

```
header( 'Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate' );
header( 'Location: ' . $permalink, true, 307 );
exit;
```